# Open a Form under a DataGridView Cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I try to open a form just below a `DataGridView` header cell. I have this (and it is not working):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form aForm = new Form();

    aForm.Text = @"Test";
    aForm.Top = this.Top + dataGridView1.Top - dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 0, false).Height;
    aForm.Left =  this.Left + dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, 0, false).Left;
    aForm.Width = 25;
    aForm.Height = 100;
    aForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

I don't see how to get the right top and left based on the `DataGridView` cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should you consider to use a Form, you have to calculate its Location using Screen coordinates:

```
Form form = new Form();
form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
form.Size = new Size(dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Width, 100);

Point c = dataGridView1.PointToScreen(dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(
                                      dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, 
                                      dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex, false).Location);
form.Location = new Point(c.X, c.Y);
form.BringToFront();
form.Show(this);
```

If you find youself in trouble using a Form, you might consider using a Panel instead:

```
Point c = dataGridView1.PointToScreen(dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex, 
                        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex, false).Location);
Point r = this.PointToClient(c);
panel1.Location = new Point(r.X, r.Y);
panel1.BringToFront();
```

Take also a look at [How do I to get the current cell position x and y in a DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619746/how-do-i-to-get-the-current-cell-position-x-and-y-in-a-datagridview)
and [Position new form directly under Datagridview selected row of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684387/winforms-position-new-form-directly-under-datagridview-selected-row-of-parent)